Can I run 2-2-4 individual wires from the meter base to the panel?
New construction home. Meter base is on front outside of garage. Service panel at rear wall.  I've already run 2-2-4 SER from my meter base to my sub/main panel. The meter base has a main service breaker. New construction in California.
The 2-2-4 I have run is not in a single sheath, but 3 individual wires. I've been told that California requires it be sheathed as one or run in conduit. My questions are: is this correct, and if not, is there anything I can wrap the wires with that will satisfy California code?

@Jack OP stated meter base has main breaker. So short run to first breaker is good. Leaves open the question of what is main vs disconnect which affects grounding.

The rule isn't just California, it is pretty much everywhere. Individual wires have insulation (except ground or in certain cases neutral) that protects against zapping people/short circuits, but they need additional protection from all sorts of damage, though how much extra protection they need varies by situation.
The two choices are cable and conduit. There are a number of different types of cable, with the biggest difference being that some are usable in dry locations (therefore mostly indoors) and some can be used in wet locations. Cables all basically look the same, and you can't turn individual wires into cable.
Conduit includes two types of PVC - schedule 40 and schedule 80, as well as a few types of metal conduit and a few other possibilities.
Your options here are to install conduit (most likely it will need one of the heavier duty types of conduit such as Rigid Metal Conduit or PVC 80) and then run the wires through the conduit, or to replace the wires with an appropriately rated cable.
You should also clarify the meter "main service breaker" details. If that breaker is labeled and installed purely as a "service disconnect" then your "sub/main panel" is the true main panel. But if that "main service breaker" is acting as the "main panel" for your installation then you need to:

Separate ground from neutral in your "sub/main panel" - which is then truly a subpanel.
Connect the ground rods to that main breaker box (a.k.a., "meter main").
Run a ground wire from the "main service breaker" to your subpanel. Meaning not 2/2/4 but rather 2/2/4/6, assuming this is 100A service.



I've already run 2-2-4 SER


The 2-2-4 I have run is not in a single sheath, but 3 individual wires

These two statements conflict. SER is sold as a cable in a sheath.
First, individual wires must be run inside conduit or other raceway.
Second, the wires require individual markings to indicate their type.  You aren't allowed to pinky-promise that you tore these out of SER and didn't buy them on wish.com.
On your "running 3 wires past the first breaker", this means you will never be allowed to install loads out at the meter-main unless they are one of the exceptions listed in NEC 220.82.   This also has an impact on your "sub" panel.

If the subpanel has a main disconnect/main breaker at the sub, then you must label it according to NEC 230.85(1) and the outside breaker according to NEC 230.85(2) or (3).  Note that a "main disconnect" may comprise up to six hand throws, and here, "handle-ties" are your friend because they can tie 2-3 independent breakers to be 1 hand throw.
If the subpanel has more than 6 throws, then the 3-wire installation is improper and must be redone either with 4-wire or with continuous non-flex metal conduit to serve as the ground.  This is a good time to correct any wire labeling issues.

Regardless, grounding and bonding must be proper. The ground rods must be a continuous run of wire to the "service disconnect" presumably indoors given the 3-wire arrangement.  However, the metal parts of the meter-main must also be grounded and bonded per NEC 230.82(3), or rather, part VII and V of Article 250.
